# Streambuilder not receiving some snapshot data

Tags: dart, flutter

I am just testing some streams from a GPS. I could plug in the gps stream directly, but I want to separate this for the moment. So I can using a StreamBuilder with my own created stream.

This all seems to be working, but the Streambuilder seems to 'miss' certain snapshots, which has me confused. Shouldn't it be guaranteed to receive all data from the stream (if it's not a broadcast)? Or am I using streams incorrectly ?

If you look at the data added/received, I can see count 5 & 7 were both added, but never received. If I just 'listen' the data without the StreamBuilder, all of the data seems to appear.

Streambuilder code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ApplicationBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        stream: bloc.gps.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot){
          if( snapshot.hasData ) {
            print("Receiving ${snapshot.data['count']}");
            return Text("${snapshot.data['timestamp']}\n${snapshot.data['latitude']},${snapshot.data['longitude']}\n",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,);
          } else {
            return Text('waiting for GPS...', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,);
          }
        }
    );

  }
```

Add to stream code:

```
var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0, timeInterval: 1, forceAndroidLocationManager: false);

    final Geolocator geoLocator = new Geolocator();
    geoLocator.getPositionStream( locationOptions ).listen(
            (Position position) {
              _count++;
              Map<String, dynamic> listenerCurrentLocation = {
                'latitude'  : position.latitude,
                'longitude' : position.longitude,
                'speed'     : position.speed,
                'accuracy'  : position.accuracy,
                'altitude'  : position.altitude,
                'timestamp' : position.timestamp,
                'count'     : _count,
              };
              print( "Adding: $listenerCurrentLocation");
              gpsController.sink.add( listenerCurrentLocation );
            });
```

Output from Run console

```
I/flutter (16345): Receiving 2
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 11.7, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:02.000Z, count: 3}
I/flutter (16345): Receiving 3
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 11.7, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:03.000Z, count: 4}
I/flutter (16345): Receiving 4
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 11.7, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:04.000Z, count: 5}
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 0.0, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:04.000Z, count: 6}
I/flutter (16345): Receiving 6
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 11.7, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:05.000Z, count: 7}
I/flutter (16345): Adding: {latitude: 50.829798333333336, longitude: -0.18484833333333334, speed: 0.0, accuracy: 20.0, altitude: 0.0, timestamp: 2019-01-13 14:21:05.000Z, count: 8}
I/flutter (16345): Receiving 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

As opposed to using `stream.listen`, `StreamBuilder` calls its builder only when a new frame is requested.

It is fine because `StreamBuilder` should be used *only* to build the layout, in which case it doesn't matter if a value is missed.

If this behavior is undesired, consider switching to a manual listening instead:

```
Stream stream;
StreamSubscription sub;

initState() {
  super.initState();
  sub = stream.listen((value) {
    // do something with `value`
  });
}


dispose() {
  sub.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: What dictates when a new frame is requested, I assumed this was when new data arrived ? I'm trying to understand if the user could be left without an important piece of information on the display. I am not calling setState anywhere, so wouldn't it not display at all. I thought the idea of a StreamBuilder was to avoid calling setState ?

Comment: It depends on the device used, like the refresh rate of the screen or its performances. With 30 fps, your `StreamBuilder` will be called _at most_ 30 times a second.

Comment: `StreamBuilder` internally calls `setState`.