# StreamBuilder Widget not building all events sent into the stream

Tags: flutter, stream, stream-builder

StreamBuilder claims to build the UI when new data is in the stream. But it is not building all the snapshots in the stream. Can anyone please explain this behaviour? What is the purpose of it if it does not build all the data in the stream.

I found a question on this issue. But it is not clear.
[Streambuilder not receiving some snapshot data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169848/streambuilder-not-receiving-some-snapshot-data)

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html - read the second paragraph (just below the youtube video)

Comment: Thanks @pskink for pointing out. So as I understood , the builder may be called with any sub-sequence of snapshots which depends on the relative timing of events produced by the stream and the build rate of the Flutter pipeline, so it may not build ALL the data which is in the stream. So is there any other way in which I can display all the data in the stream in UI?

Comment: I know that stream.listen((value){}) will listen to all the data. But how to use it in building the widget?

Comment: what data do you have in your stream?

Comment: I am getting the data from MQTT , it is a  JSON data, making an object of a user-defined class with the data, and I am adding the object into the stream.

Comment: instead of `stream: stream` use `stream: stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder)` or just `stream.transform(utf8.fuse(json))` - more https://dart.dev/articles/archive/converters-and-codecs

Comment: Can you please explain why stream.transform is required in this case? My query was that whether there is any alternative of StreamBuilder to build my widgets based on every data in the stream.

Comment: ok, to clarify: for example your stream has 10 chunks of json data - do you want your widget to be rebuilt 10 times or only once when all the chunks are received?

Comment: It is ok to rebuild the widget once all the 10 chunks are received. But ALL 10 chunks are necessary to rebuild the widget.

Comment: so use Stream.fold / Stream.reduce / Stream.toArray or similar stuff and FutureBuilder that builds the result

Comment: ok, I will look into it. Thanks @pskink